# Changed /etc ownership to my account now logged out of sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, ftp, error-handling

I was working on some SFTP via filezilla to allow download and reupload of some file I took owner ship via ROOT and chown -R 'myusername' /etc and chmod 777 my user account for -R /etc

Now I got timed out and tried to login to root again and it gives me error
  sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
  sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
  sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
I have access to the /etc and 777 on all the files and also can access them via FTP so please suggest how to restore access to the root account
Also the root as no password at this time so i cant run the general pkexec or visudo commands.

Please suggest a solution and also if there is a way to manually reset the /etc/shadow or passwd files.

I think it is slightly different than the indicated duplicate
Becuse i changed the permissions on the files too.
Also if i run 
chown root:root /etc/
it will give me 
 chown root:root /etc
chown: changing ownership of '/etc': Operation not permitted

Thank You!

Comment: also i ran ls -al /etc | grep sudoers           
THis returned :
-rwxrwxrwx   1 offc offc   755 Jul  4  2017 sudoers
drwxrwxrwx   2 offc root      4096 Jun  8 01:22 sudoers.d

Comment: ls -al /etc/sudoers.d
returned

drwxrwxrwx   2 offc root 4096 Jun  8 01:22 .
drwxrwxrwx 109 offc root 4096 Jun  8 02:14 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 offc root  126 Mar  4 01:50 90-cloud-init-users
-rwxrwxrwx   1 offc root  958 Mar 30  2016 README
-r--r-----   1 root     root   47 Jun  8 01:32 waagent

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to fix this will require a reboot.  Here's two solutions that come to mind:

1. Boot ubuntu livecd and mount the device that has `/etc`.  Then do a `chown -R root:root /path/to/etc`.
2. If yo don't have a livecd or way to boot the livecd, try this.  Reboot your computer.  When you get to the grub prompt edit the boot entry on the line with the `linux` command to append `break=bottom` (this may require you hold the `<shift>` key while booting).  Then hit the `<F10>` key to boot the modified boot entry.  This will give you a root shell in the initrd where the rootfs and `/dev` is mounted.  Next do `/bin/chroot /root` to chroot into the rootfs. If `/etc` is not on the rootfs, then mount the device at say `/tmp`.  Then you can do `chown -R root:root /path/to/etc`.  If you mounted `/etc`, be sure to unmount it when done, and then exit the chroot and the initrd shell to continue booting normally.  Your `/etc` files should have all root permission.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response
This is on a Azure VM 
I am not sure how we can reset it upon reboot

Comment: I have no experience with Azure, but some googling suggests that you can create a new temporary VM that runs the livecd. Then attach the harddrive with the bad /etc and use method 1.  Method 2 might be able to be used by attaching to the VM via a virtual serial port.